# Why has mongorestore stopped recognizing the --ssl option

Tags: mongodb

I've been using a mongorestore command to move data into our production db. But it's recently stopped working. The command is

```
mongorestore --db import --collection intent --host Cluster0-shard-0/cluster0-shard-00-00-wr3bj.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-wr3bj.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-wr3bj.mongodb.net:27017 --username usr --password pswd --ssl --authenticationDatabase admin intent.bson
```

And I'm getting a strange message saying

```
error parsing command line options: unknown option "ssl"
```

This doesn't make much sense as the option is listed in the [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#cmdoption-ssl)

I think I may have upgraded from 3.2 to 3.4 since I last ran the command.

I'm running mongo on OS X and I installed using the instructions [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/) (with curl not brew).

```
Ewen-Macbook:~ aidan$ mongorestore --version
mongorestore version: r3.4.2
git version: 3f76e40c105fc223b3e5aac3e20dcd026b83b38b
Go version: go1.7
   os: darwin
   arch: amd64
   compiler: gc
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The "unknown option" message is expected for `mongorestore` builds compiled without SSL support. As noted in the docs "Most MongoDB distributions include support for TLS/SSL", but there are some exceptions depending on your install method and O/S . What is your O/S version and output of  `mongorestore --version`? How did you install or upgrade `mongorestore`?

Answer (score 2):

The instructions for installing on OS X [manually via `curl`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#download-the-binary-files-for-the-desired-release-of-mongodb) currently use the non-SSL version as an example and do not actually link to the latest version (eg. 3.4.2 is included at the moment but 3.4.4 is the latest production release). I've raised [DOCS-10176](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-10176) to correct this information.

In the interim, if you visit the [MongoDB Download Center](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community) which is referenced directly above the `curl` step you can find links for of the available packages to download. The OS X downloads for MongoDB 3.0+ should all default to a version with SSL support, or explicitly highlight if a selected distribution does not include SSL encryption.